# Two point crossover operation

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm, crossover

I've been trying to write a code for two point crossover operation in a genetic algorithm. At first two random gene location is selected. After that, two chromosomes swap their genes which are located btw random numbers called genelocation1 and genelocatıon2.

```
for example  First Gene [0.3,0.2,0.4,0,0.1,0.5,0.7]
             Second Gene [0.25,0.6,0.45,0.15,0.80,0.9,0.85]
        rndm    genelocation1=3
           rdnm  gnelocation2 =5
child Gene1 [0.3,0.2,0.4,0.15,0.80,0.5,0.7]
      Gene2 [0.25, 0.6, 0.45, 0, 0.1,0.9,0.85]
```

my problem is this: since two numbers are generated randomly, i could not define an array like array[genelocation2-genelocation1]..  How can i solve the problem. here is my whole code about two point crossover. pointers maybe a solution but i am not good at pointers.

Here is the code:

```
void Xover (int mother,int father)
{
    int tempo;
    int Rndmgenelocation1=(rand()%ActivityNumber);
    int Rndmgenelocation2=(rand()%ActivityNumber);

    if (Rndmgenelocation1>Rndmgenelocation2)//sure that 2>1
    {
        tempo=Rndmgenelocation1;
        Rndmgenelocation1=Rndmgenelocation2;
        Rndmgenelocation2=tempo;
    }

    int size=(Rndmgenelocation2-Rndmgenelocation1);
    int Temp1[size];//this makes an error

    int ppp=Rndmgenelocation1;
    for (int pp=Rndmgenelocation1;pp<Rndmgenelocation2;pp++)
    {
        Temp1[pp]=Sol_list[father].Chromosome[ppp];
        ppp++;
    }
    int pppx=Rndmgenelocation1;
    for (int ppx=Rndmgenelocation1;ppx<Rndmgenelocation2;ppx++)
    {
        Sol_list[father].Chromosome[ppx]=Sol_list[mother].Chromosome[pppx];
        pppx++;
    }
    int ppplx=Rndmgenelocation1;
    for (int pplx=Rndmgenelocation1;pplx<Rndmgenelocation2;pplx++)
    {
        Sol_list[father].Chromosome[pplx]=Temp1[ppplx];
        ppplx++;
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of your variables? Is mother/father the value itself or an index to some array? What is ActivityNumber? What's the structure of Sol_list?

Comment: mother and father are chromosomes which i stated in the beginning as first gene and second gene.I wrote "gene" wrongly it should be "chromosome". Anyway, Activity number is the lenght of gene (in this example 7). Sol_list[].Chromosome[] structure is the arrays which i store previous population. (Example: Sol_list[1].Chromosome is a solution from previous population, like first gene, second gene)

Comment: my code maybe strange to you. I accept your own codes but ıt should include same operation which i stated in the beginning. two point crossover.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define an array of variable size on the stack.
You could use

```
int *Temp1=new int[size]
```

You then must not forget to call

```
delete[] Temp1;
```

at the end of your function!

edit:

I didn't test my code below, but the following should do what you want in a more efficient (and more understandable) way:

```
#include <algorithm>
void Xover (int mother,int father)
{
    int Rndmgenelocation1=(rand()%ActivityNumber);
    int Rndmgenelocation2=(rand()%ActivityNumber);

    if (Rndmgenelocation1>Rndmgenelocation2)//sure that 2>1
    {
        std::swap(Rndmgenelocation1,Rndmgenelocation2);
    }

    for (int pp=Rndmgenelocation1;pp<Rndmgenelocation2;pp++)
    {
        std::swap(Sol_list[father].Chromosome[pp],Sol_list[mother].Chromosome[pp]);
    }
    return;
}
```

edit2:

I just found [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap_ranges/) another even better way - the STL implements a ready-to-use cross over algorithm. Use:

```
#include <algorithm>
void Xover (int mother,int father)
{
    int Rndmgenelocation1=(rand()%ActivityNumber);
    int Rndmgenelocation2=(rand()%ActivityNumber);

    if (Rndmgenelocation1>Rndmgenelocation2)//sure that 2>1
    {
        std::swap(Rndmgenelocation1,Rndmgenelocation2);
    }

    std::swap_ranges(
        Sol_list[father].Chromosome[Rndmgenelocation1],
        Sol_list[father].Chromosome[Rndmgenelocation2],
        Sol_list[mother].Chromosome[Rndmgenelocation1]
    );

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it give no error but doesnot solve my problem.  Can i use Temp1[0] or Temp1[1] to store values if i define Temp1 as a pointer? or what should i use

Comment: Variable array sizes are allowed as an extension in `gcc` and `g++`.

Comment: You have the same access via Temp1[0] or Temp[1] as in your code. Just the declaration and the deletion of Temp1 are different. If you want to use your approach with the temp array, you could also consider using std::vector, like Jason states in his answer. But I would recommend to you to not use a temp array and directly swap the elements (see one of the edits of my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you must not be using `g++` as your compiler.  If so, you can use a `std::vector` rather than an array.  Simply do

```
std::vector<int> array(size);
```

Now you can treat it like a "normal" array though the `operator[]` syntax.  There's also no concern about memory leaks from forgetting to call `delete` on a pointer.